# ListPlot and ListLinePlot not working for imported files

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, data

I have a for loop which is supposed to generate a bunch of different values. I then exported these values in a file from which I am trying to extract and plot the data.
I use

```
data=Import["filelocation","format"]
```

The data extracted is of the form:

```
{{"{1.573749252582194", 
  "0.04821829551516154}"}, {"{0.8475790113766317", 
  "0.08707545494516936}"}, {"{0.8447949487122333", 
  "0.07913547594124097}"}, {"{0.9410297126818918", 
  "0.07098854021310264}"}}
```

This is being read by mathematica and I can print it out however,the code

```
ListPlot[data[[All,1]],data[[All,2]]]
```

gives me an empty graph. I have tried saving to both csv as well as txt files and neither work. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Try exporting to .dat format or to .txt but with `Export[..., "Data"]`.

Comment: The imported data is odd because the " and { are not correctly nested. Try `data // Map[StringReplace[#, {"{" -> "", "}" -> ""}] &] // ToExpression // ListPlot`